# Excluding automatically test without @Test

Tags: maven, testing, junit

We have a Java project which relies on Junit and failsafe plug-in to execute the test cases. In order to select the test cases to execute we have created our own @Category annotation and we mark each test to execute with our annotation. In the pom.xml we have added the parameter  referring to our annotation. 
The approach is fine and it works. 
Now, what I'd like to do is:
- to get rid of @Category annotation, marking each test to execute is boring
- find a way to exclude automatically all those tests that do not have @Test (we have some super-class that do not need to be executed on their own).

As an example, I have the super-class SetEnvConditionTest.java then its subclass VerifyLogIn. SetEnvCondition has only two methods; setup and teardown, When I execute VerifyLogin it calls parent setup method (the same for tear down) and then its method marked with  "@Test". The class SetEnvCondition has no "@Test" method (I need it only for setting the environment), if it it is executed  a "missing test method" exception arises.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Make the first separation of the test categories based in general on the naming conventions (details see the docs of the plugins). One for unit tests (which will be run be maven-surefire-plugin) and the integration tests which will be run by maven-failsafe-plugin. Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: First, let's say that all the tests are for integration, I don't need to diversify between integration and unit tests.

Comment: So you should name according to the naming convention like [`**IT.java`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes)...

Comment: It is not sufficient to name according the convention. Have you read the example?

Comment: At the end, we renamed the super-class with the suffix "Base" and leveraged on the naming convention, as you suggested.